# How do I convert a char* to a char* that is UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, utf-8

Under Windows I use MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, ...) and WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, ...) for the conversion.

How do I do the same thing under OS X and Linux? I tried mbstowcs/wcstombs but the resulting char* is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [iconv(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/iconv.3.html). that's the api you want. You'll need `-liconv`.

Comment: Actually I did but I did not understand how to use this API and what library I have to link to. Do you have an example?

Comment: OK, and how do I know the input encoding that the user currently has (the variable EUCSET in this example)?

Comment: @nefch you have to know. You can't guess. Depending where the input is coming from you may be able to find out, but if it's not told to you by your source, then you need to have it defined elsewhere.

Comment: @nefch: If you're looking for an equivalent to Windows CP_ACP (the user's default ANSI codepage), it's always UTF-8 on OS X, and on most modern linux distros as well, so there's no conversion to be done. If the input data isn't in the use's default codepage, you've got the same problem you do on Windows…